# How to view Vertex AI Matching Engine Deployed Index logs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have deployed an index in Vertex AI IndexEndpoint. According to the docs for [DeployedIndex](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1beta1.types.DeployedIndex), I have set the attribute `enable_access_logging` to `True` to enable private endpoints access logs.

> **enable_access_logging**
> Optional. If true, private endpoint's access logs are sent to StackDriver Logging. These logs are like standard server access logs, containing information like timestamp and latency for each MatchRequest. Note that Stackdriver logs may incur a cost, especially if the deployed index receives a high queries per second rate (QPS). Estimate your costs before enabling this option.

However, in cloud logging I only see Vertex AI audit logs and no access logs. Where can I find logs that contain information for timestamp and latency for each request?

Deployed Index Configuration

```
createTime: '2021-11-24T10:59:51.975949Z'
deployedIndexes:
- automaticResources:
    maxReplicaCount: 1
    minReplicaCount: 1
  createTime: '2021-12-13T16:37:27.030230Z'
  deploymentGroup: default
  displayName: glove_brute_force_deployed_V1
  enableAccessLogging: true
  id: glove_brute_force_deployed_V1
  index: projects/XXXXXXXXXXXX/locations/us-central1/indexes/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  indexSyncTime: '2021-12-13T20:19:00.874937Z'
  privateEndpoints:
    matchGrpcAddress: 10.242.0.5
displayName: index_endpoint_for_demo
etag: AMEw9yNMD_AR3V6LIrGln9Ye5PuWWYAOoJwxgSHs2T2Xt8iwAPv1mLOZTfaDMLFTAaBC
name: projects/XXXXXXXXXXXX/locations/us-central1/indexEndpoints/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
network: projects/XXXXXXXXXXXX/global/networks/NETWORK_ID
updateTime: '2021-11-24T10:59:53.271100Z'
```

Cloud Logging

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You enabled the access logging correctly, but the resource that you are trying to use on your query is not the correct to find these logs: on the screen shot that you attached, you are looking for the `Audit Logs`

You should look for `aiplatform.googleapis.com/Endpoint` resource type. You can directly wrote the logging query as the following one:

```
resource.type="aiplatform.googleapis.com/IndexEndpoint" 
resource.labels.endpoint_id="{YOUR_ENDPOINT_ID}" 
resource.labels.location="us-central1"
```

Or, if you prefer to use the UI dropdown, you can find this resource on `Vertex AI Endpoint`.

[image: UI resource dropdown]

You can also recover the logs via [`gcloud CLI` command or using API calls](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/audit-logging#viewing_logs) instead using the console UI. Depending on your use case it could be useful.

Comment: With matching engine, `resource.type="aiplatform.googleapis.com/IndexEndpoint"` and `resource.labels.index_endpoint_id={YOUR_ENDPOINT_ID}` worked for me

Comment: You are right `/Endpoint` is for prediction. I already edited my answer